# Looping over the first 100 values then looping over the next 100 values

Tags: r, vector, split

I have a vector of True and False values. The length of the vector is 1000.

```
vect <- [T T F T F F..... x1000]
```

I want loop over the first 100 (i.e 1:100) values and calculate the count of true and false values and store the result into some variable (e.g. True <- 51, False <- 49). Then loop over the next 100 values (101:200) and do the same computation as before, and so on till I reach 1000.

The code below is pretty standard but, instead of slicing the vector, it calculates sums for the entire vector.

```
count_True = 0
count_False = 0
for (i in vect){
    if (i == 'T'){
        count_True = count_True + 1
    }
    else {
        count_false = count_false + 1
    }
}
```

I am aware you can split the the vector by

```
vect_splt <- split(vect,10)
```

but is there a way to combine these to do what I wanted or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work:

```
set.seed(42)
vect <- sample(rep(c(T, F), 500))

vect <- tibble(vect)
vect %>%
  mutate(seq = row_number() %/% 100) %>%
  group_by(seq) %>%
  summarise(n_TRUE = sum(vect),
            n_FALSE = sum(!vect))
# A tibble: 11 x 3
     seq n_TRUE n_FALSE
   <dbl>  <int>   <int>
 1     0     42      57
 2     1     56      44
 3     2     50      50
 4     3     55      45
 5     4     43      57
 6     5     48      52
 7     6     48      52
 8     7     54      46
 9     8     51      49
10     9     53      47
11    10      0       1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have another dataset  with (TP,TN,FP,FN,.... x 1000). Can something similar be done to count some of TP,TN,FP,FN for each 100 data points?
TP: True Positive
TN: True Negative
FP: False Positive
FN: False Negative

Comment: You can use that field in the `group_by` section and summarise with count using `n()`

Answer (score 0):

We can use a `split` by `table`. With a grouping index created with `gl`, `split` the `vector` into a `list` of `vector`s and get the count with `table` and store it in a `list`

```
out <- lapply(split(vect, as.integer(gl(length(vect), 100, length(vect)))), table)
```

It can be converted to a single dataset by `rbind`ing

```
out1 <- do.call(rbind, out)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
vect <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 1000, replace  = TRUE)
```